# Similar program in Java shows a different value

Tags: php

When the value of $gpa/$numrows is 3.35, I get "Grade A" echoed, but when the value is 3.2, I get B+. I have no idea why this is happening. I'm still expecting Grade A for 3.2 as I program it in Java. Please, help me figure out this minor issue which has got me stuck for a while.

```
if ($gpa/$numrows>=3.6) {
            echo "<br>GRADE: A+";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=3.2 and ($gpa/$numrows)<3.6) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: A";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=2.8 and ($gpa/$numrows)<3.2) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: B+";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=2.4 and ($gpa/$numrows)<2.8) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: B";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=2 and ($gpa/$numrows)<2.4) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: C+";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=1.6 and ($gpa/$numrows)<2) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: C";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=1.2 and ($gpa/$numrows)<1.6) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: D+";
    }
    elseif (($gpa/$numrows)>=0.8 and ($gpa/$numrows)<1.2) {
        echo "<br>GRADE: D";
    }
    else{
        echo "<br>GRADE: E";
    }
```

Comment: This is probably a problem with floating point inaccuracy. What are your exact input values for those two variables?

Comment: You are right. It was because of the floating-point inaccuracy. I used round() for all divisions, now it seems to fix the value.  

Like: round(($gpa/$numrows),3)